# how to select special character in oracle under linux environment

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus

Can you please help me regarding

How to select below query in Oracle.

I am trying to spool a special character from SQL*plus. But it is showing like `????`

```
select  '§' from dual;
```

Comment: Read http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/09/24/why-are-junk-values-displayed-in-my-client/

Answer (score 1):

Unless your database character set is defined to `US7ASCII` this should be no problem.

You local character set has to match setting of `NLS_LANG`.
Example:

```
$ locale charmap
UTF-8
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

Then `NLS_LANG` environment variable should be set to 
`NLS_LANG={your_language}_{your_country}.AL32UTF8`

Then SQL*Plus should work fine.